# Prove inequality of series sum by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How should i prove by induction that:

$ 1 + 2^{(-2)} + 3^{-2} + ...+n^{(-2)} \le 2-n^{-1} $

I haven't had inequalities with sum of series at the class about induction so i can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: Hint: It is very easy to see this if you use $$\frac1{n^2}\le\frac{1}{(n-1)n}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1n$$ (You may also be interested in the Basel problem)

Comment: This should be possible to solve with the examples that you saw in class. Basically, it is the same idea (begin with the case $n = 1$. Next assume that is it true for some $n = k$ and then prove it for the following number, i.e. $n = k + 1$). There is no reason to think that exists a new trick to use, much less another procedure. Just start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction is induction.

Base case:  $1^{-2} = 1 \le 2- 1^{-1} = 1$.

Induction case:

If $1 + 2^{-2}+ 3^{-2} + ....... + n^{-2} \le 2-n^{-1}$ then

$1 + 2^{-2}+ 3^{-2} + ....... + n^{-2} + (n+1)^{-2} \le 2-n^{-1} + (n+1)^{-2}$.

So all we have to do is prove $ 2-n^{-1} + (n+1)^{-2} \le 2- (n+1)^{-1}$.

Can we do that?

All we have to do is calculate that

$2 - \frac 1n + \frac 1{(n+1)^2} =$

$2-(\frac 1n - \frac 1{(n+1)^2}) =$

$2 - (\frac {(n+1)^2- n}{n(n+1)^2} )=$

$2 - (\frac {n^2 +n + 1}{n(n+1)^2} )<$

$2 - (\frac {n^2 + n}{n(n+1)^2}) =$

$2- \frac {n+1}{(n+1)^2} =$

$2-\frac 1{n+1}=  2-(n+1)^{-1}$.

And that's it.

So $1 + 2^{-2}+ 3^{-2} + ....... + n^{-2} + (n+1)^{-2} \le 2-n^{-1} + (n+1)^{-2}<  2-(n+1)^{-1}$

Comment: What if we had a "less than" sign instead of a "less or equal to" sign? Would we then have to show that $2-n^{-1} + (n+1)^{-2} < 2- (n+1)^{-1}
$, we would expand both sides and compare and if true, then we are done.

Comment: The only case where they are equal is $n=1$.  In the induction step showed that if LHS for $n$ was $\le$ RHS for $n$ then LHS for $n+1$ is *strictly* less than RHS for $n+1$. So we have actually proven that it is strictly less for all cases but $n=1$.  We don't have to do anything.